# How to report progress to background worker dowork event each line and add it to a richtextbox and update a progressbar?

Tags: c#, winforms

The main goal is to format the json file content to some beauty and nice text format and show it in the richtextbox. something that will be displayed in more human readable text format.

I have a richtextbox and a progressbar and a backgroundworker.

I want to read from array of lines string[] each line and report it to the backgroundworker progresschanged event so it will add to the richtextbox each line and also will update the progressbar from 0% to 100%.

I want the formatted JSON to be displayed in the jsonFormattedRichTextBox with a nice visual effect and a progress bar, which should indicate the progress of both the formatting and adding the text to the jsonFormattedRichTextBox

but what it does now it's getting to the method FormatJson in the dowork event and not reporting to the progressbar anything at that point and i want to report to the progressbar1 the whole processing not only the string[] lines part.

and when it's getting to the string[] lines part the whole application freezing. i  can see the progressbar progress moving up but the application is freezing i can't bring the application up.

The code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Format_Json
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string selectedFilePath = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnFormat.Enabled = false;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(selectedFilePath);
        }

        private void btnJsonFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.Filter = "JSON Files|*.json|All Files|*.*";
                openFileDialog.Title = "Select a JSON File";

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    selectedFilePath = openFileDialog.FileName; // Store the selected file path
                    if (File.Exists(selectedFilePath))
                    {
                        textBoxJsonPath.Text = selectedFilePath;
                        //backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(selectedFilePath); // Start background processing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jsonFormattedRichTextBox.Text = "File not found";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private string FormatJson(JToken token, string indent)
        {
            if (token is JContainer container)
            {
                var formattedJson = "{\n";
                foreach (var pair in container)
                {
                    formattedJson += indent + "  \"" + pair.Path + "\": ";
                    formattedJson += FormatJson(pair, indent + "  ");
                    formattedJson += ",\n";
                }
                formattedJson = formattedJson.Remove(formattedJson.Length - 2); // Remove the trailing comma
                formattedJson += "\n" + indent + "}";
                return formattedJson;
            }
            else if (token is JValue value)
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedFilePath = e.Argument as string;
            if (File.Exists(selectedFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(selectedFilePath);
                    JToken parsedJson = JToken.Parse(jsonContent);
                    string formattedJson = FormatJson(parsedJson, ""); // Format JSON using the FormatJson method

                    // Split the formatted JSON into lines and report progress for each line
                    string[] lines = formattedJson.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    int totalLines = lines.Length;
                    int linesProcessed = 0;
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        int progress = (linesProcessed * 100) / totalLines;
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress, line);
                        linesProcessed++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    e.Result = "Error reading or formatting JSON: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Result = "File not found";
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here, you can update the progress bar for the entire processing.
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            string formattedJson = e.UserState as string;
            jsonFormattedRichTextBox.AppendText(formattedJson + "\n"); // Append the formatted text line by line
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnFormat.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Value = 100; // Set the progress bar to 100% when completed
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                jsonFormattedRichTextBox.Text = "An error occurred: " + e.Error.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `FormatJson` method does all the work in one go and just returns the final results. You need to have it return the results one line at a time. For that you should use an iterator. That is the term that you should research. Learn how they work and then make your best effort to implement one here. If what you do doesn't work, we can help you fix it.